# AutoComplete not working, either with keyboard or with menu

Tags: autocomplete, c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

Just getting started with C++Builder.   Watching a tutorial, my installation's AutoComplete doesn't seem to be working properly.  I can't find any option to fix it.

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, nothing happens, anywhere (in the tutorial, it works in several places).

I've even used the menu selection for the same feature ("View -> Editor -> Complete Code") but nothing happens.

Any idea how to turn this feature on?

Using "Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.4 Version 27.0.40680.4203"

Comment: Which compiler are you using? The code completion doesn't work properly with the CLANG-enhanced compilers.

Comment: Kerem is correct: with 10.4.2 the code completion for either Clang32 or Clang64 compilers does not work. For 10.4.2 it does word for the Win32 "classic" compiler.

Comment: By the way: The latest version 11.1.5 (note the ".5 was only released mid July 2022) does have working code completion for Win32 classic, clang32 and clang64